# animate.css loop 2 different animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, bootstrap-4

I'm running recently into a problem with animate.css on my latest project.

Basically what I'm trying to do is refreshing a paragraph text on my webpage every five/ten seconds with jQuery, but I don't want to simply change the text. I would like that the previous text disappears using animate.css *fadeOut* animation and the new one appears using the *fadeIn* animation.

Currently I'm using this code (is only an exmple):

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("#myp").addClass('fadeOut');
  $("#myp").text(sometext);
  $("#myp").removeClass('fadeOut');
  $("#myp").addClass('fadeIn');
  $("#myp").removeClass('fadeIn');
}, 5000);
```

Obviously `sometext` is every cycle different for simplicity.

At first, this code gave me some problem because the animation was not smooth but flickery. I tried to slow down the process by sleeping the programm using `setTimeout` between the add and the remove class, because I was thinking that the removing of the class before the end of css animation could cause the problem but is still flickery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest some `setTimeOut` methods inside the `setInterval` function.
So you can control the time of each step of the animation.

In addition, since animate.css uses `animation` property, you also need to determine the `animation-duration` and `animation-fill-mode` in CSS.

`animation-duration` specifies how long the animation cycle should take.
`animation-fill-mode` with "forwards" will prevent the element from being reset to the previous state after animation completion.

```js
var sometext = "another text";

setInterval(function() {
  
    var myp = $("#myp");
    myp.addClass('fadeOut');
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      myp.text(sometext);
      myp.removeClass('fadeOut');
      myp.addClass('fadeIn');
      
      setTimeout(function() {
         myp.removeClass('fadeIn');
      }, 1000);
      
    }, 1000);
  
}, 5000);
```

```css
#myp {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myp">lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
```